# Angular:How to load the image in full before I navigate to the page?

Tags: angular, image

I tried to add a delay between navigation and navigation but still the image takes time to load

ts:

```
navigate(name:string,title:string) {
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'success',
      title: `You go to the page ${title}`,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500,
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate([`${name}`]);
    }
      , 1500);
  }
```

html:

```
 <div class="home-container">
          <li (click)="navigate('home','Home')"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="house"
              class="svg-inline--fa fa-house " role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"
              color="#4d4d4e">
              <path fill="currentColor"
                d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1h-32l.7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1V472c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H456c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1H416 392c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V448 384c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32H256c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32v64 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40H160 128.1c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2H104c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40V360c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8V287.6H32c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z">
              </path>
            </svg>
            <span class="home">Home</span>
          </li>
        </div>
```

html image in the home page:

```
<img class="mor-image" src="../../assets/images/Mor.png" alt="mor">
```

Comment: You could use a router resolver with `this.http.get('./assets/images/Mor.png')` or similar as return in the resolve method. But this is not a recommended approach. A component which has a loading style (think how youtube does it) until data passed in. Angular 15 introduces an image directive that does this https://angular.io/guide/image-directive

Comment: The img element has a `complete` event which will be called if the source fully loaded. You can use a placehoder/loadingspinner or other things while loading. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete
By the way: It's a bad user experience if the screen "froze" while loading a image in background. So navigate and use a loading spinner is the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay won't do the job in this case. The reason is the image only load when you're in the page.
There's a trick to connect faster which is use the `preload` attribute. This is a technique for improving loading speed of your site.

`<link rel="preload" as="image" href="image.png" />`

By putting that line to the `head` tag (just like other script tags), you're telling browsers that this is a high priority resource, so load it as soon as possible.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload