# How many images can be loading at the same time without sacrificing speed

Tags: javascript, angular, image, performance

I'm making a webcomic reader that loads 5 to 10 images whenever the user navigates to an episode. Each image is 2 to 3 megabytes. The project is in angular.

The problem is that each episode takes a while to load because all the images of an episode are loading at the same time. You can't even begin reading the episode until the entire episode is done loading.

I tried using the (load) function to stop an image from loading until the previous image is done loading. That way, the user can begin reading the episode while the rest of the episode loads. And while this did load the first image much quicker, it took an eternity to load the entire episode. My guess is because javascript can load a certain number of images at the same time through separate channels, and bottlenecking it to one image at a time takes much longer.

So is there an ideal number of images that javascript can load at the same time without sacrificing speed? Or do I just have a flawed understanding of the system.

Comment: Very broad. Specify your problem along with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the rule I know from optimizing frontend app is the less the better.
You see, the page with text only will load faster than with full of images, and page with 1 image loads faster than page with 10 images.
Assuming we have a reliable connection, good backend. Let's focus on what we can do on frontend.

- So first thing first: we want users to see the first image immediately, so we load it immediately, similar to what you did, it's just that we don't touch other images, we only explicitly load the first image. For others, we lazy load them (more on that on point 2)
  What I wanted to add more is there're also other resources such as JS/CSS/Fonts... We want our images to load first, so we need to hint to browsers that this is a high priority resource. You can find more about this by searching for ["preload" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560568/angularhow-to-load-the-image-in-full-before-i-navigate-to-the-page/74578203#74578203)
- Next, while users scroll down the page as they're reading/viewing the first image/episode, we will start loading the rest, one by one.
  This is what called "lay-loading", with this keyword you can find pretty much any kind of examples. You can take advantages of modern browsers's lazy attribute, or use IntersectionObserver to have more control over when to load

Small note: This is more of a performance question than any framework. So you could find some books about performance, they provide the background such as what is blocking and non-blocking resources, what is TTFB, LCP.
Angular recently updated with [`NgOptimizedImage`](https://angular.io/guide/image-directive), it looks promising, we don't have to do those manual works anymore (at least for the images)

Comment: While this didn't exactly answer my question, my question was worded very poorly anyways. This was still very helpful, so thank you!